# string replacing from value of database

Tags: c#, regex, string

Using **C# 4.0** , **vs10** , **ASP .Net MVC 4.0**

Here is a sample string :

```
string x = "herr <FirstName> <LastName> , \n With due respect and humble submission, I , the student of <Semester>,<Year> of <DepartmentName> of <UniversityName>."
```

I have a database with millions of rows, which has different (these) informations.

I have to check the string. Where "<>" this tags are found, for each rows of datatable, the field inside the "<>" tag will be replaced. I am not understanding what i am saying. Please let me give an example :

for each rows of datatable, when in the string,  is found, FirstName from the current DataRow will be replaced here. Like :

```
foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
{
    string body = "herr " + drow["FirstName"] + " " + drow["LastName"] + ", \n With due respect and humble submission, I , the student of " + drow["Semester"] + "," + drow["Year"] + " of " + drow["DepartmentName"] + " of " + drow["UniversityName"] + ".";

sendmail(body);
}
```

I dont have any knowledge of RegularExpression. Any simple , easy, and wise way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be using the Replace method:

```
string x = "herr <FirstName> <LastName> , \n With due respect and humble submission, I , the student of <Semester>,<Year> of <DepartmentName> of <UniversityName>."




foreach(DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
{
   string body = x.Replace("<FirstName>", drow["FirstName"]).
                Replace("<LastName>", drow["LastName"]).
                Replace("<Semester>", drow["Semester"]).
                Replace("<Year>", drow["Year"]).
                Replace("<DepartmentName>", drow["DepartmentName"]).
                Replace("<UniversityName>", drow["UniversityName"]);

    sendmail(body);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the following extension method in cases where the content between "<>" tags is not predetermined.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceString(this string s, string newString)
    {
        int startIndex = s.IndexOf("<");

        s = s.Insert(startIndex, newString);

        startIndex = s.IndexOf("<"); //redetermine the startIndex in a new string generated above
        int length = s.IndexOf(">") - startIndex + 1;

        return s.Remove(startIndex, length);
    }
}
```

The method simply searches for the first "<" and the first ">" and replaces the tags and the content within. You can use it the following way:

```
string body = x.ReplaceString(drow["value for dynamicly defined tag"]).
  ReplaceString(drow["value for dynamicly defined tag 2"])
```

and so on...

**NOTE:**

I could have used the replace method instead of first inserting new values and than removing the tags in the above example, but since the content within the tags can be dependent on the user input, two tags may have the same content and the Replace method would cause trouble in that case.

Comment: I think, this could be a great solution. I am going to trial a implementation right now. One thing that still is bothering me : <FirstName>,<LastName>... these columns are also dynamic. They are not predefined.

Answer (score 0):

string.Format is your friend here, I guess.

An example:

```
string x = string.Format("herr {0} {1} , \n With due respect and humble submission, I , the student of {2},{3} of {4} of {5}.", drow["FirstName"], drow["LastName"], drow["Semester"], drow["Year"], drow["DepartmentName"], drow["UniversityName"]);
```